# AngularFire get documents based on query from another collection

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm trying to make a Feed Page showing posts only from users I'm following.

This is the example of a post document:
[image]

And this is the example of a document of a follower relation:
[image]

I want to get posts that only come from users that I'm following, that means i must be a reference in the field "follower" and that user must be a reference both in "followed" (for the followers collection) and in "user" (for the posts collection).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To get your followers

```
const myFollowers = await getDocs(
  query(collection(this.db, 'followers'), where('follower', '==', `users/${userId}`))
).then((qDoc) => qDoc.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()!['followed']));
```

Now to get all the posts of each follower

```
let feedPosts = [];
await Promise.all(
  myFollowers.map((followerId) =>
    getDocs(query(collection(this.db, 'posts'), where('user', '==', `users/${followerId}`)))
  )
).then((qDocs) => qDocs.forEach((qDoc) => feedPosts.push(...qDoc.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))));
```